# GCloud - Where to place project when working with multiple users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, multiple-users

First of all, I'm new to the GCloud platform and to everything cloud related in general.

I want to work with multiple users (with different Google Accounts) on one project in the GCloud.
I already granted the users all the necessary rights, to access my project.

I plan on running a Kubernetes Cluster. I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app) tutorial and everything worked fine. But now I figured out, that other users can't acces my project folder, because it is in /home/USERNAME.

Also when saving some dummy file to /tmp the other users can't see it and I read, that the GCloud Shell is per user and not per project.

My question is, where can I clone my git project to on the GCloud platform so that other users can `git pull` when there are code changes? Or should I setup my project differently? Also they would need acces to the dockerfile in order to build a new image for Kubernetes.

Do I have to use a CI/CD solution? As I'm working on a school project currently, there is no need for CI/CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Github](https://github.com/), [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/), [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) or any other SCM should do. That way each of the users can have their own local repository of the code you are working on.
CI/CD is not obligatory and you can deploy your applications without it, however it can make your life easier when working with large codebases and when you are deploying often.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.
I probably was not clear with my question, sorry, my bad. I would like to now where on the GCloud I can clone my git repository to, so that all the users on that project can call `git pull` when there is a code change. They would also need access to build the new docker image.

Comment: Well, there is no need for your code to be on GCloud, only the end product, the applications you are deploying. Your code stays in your code repository (which is managed by third party) and a copy on the developers machine. Each of the devs should install GCloud SDK and authenticate in order to operate on GCE, build images, etc. For building images in particular, see https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/builds/

Comment: I only cloned the repo to the GCloud because the tutorial said that it should be done. I will try out the GCloud SDK. Thanks again for your fast answer!